# Cannot modify HERE Maps rerouting route options

Tags: android, maps, here-api, reroute

When using the reroute listener in HERE maps, I cannot seems to figure out how to modify the RouteResult that is given by onRerouteEnd. When I plot it on the map it goes through bodies of water, which I'm guessing is because the transport mode hasn't been set. Here is what I have attempted:

```
private NavigationManager.RerouteListener m_reroutinglistener = new 
NavigationManager.RerouteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRerouteBegin(){
    }

    @Override
    public void onRerouteEnd(RouteResult routeResult){
        routeResult.getRoute().getRoutePlan().getRouteOptions().setTransportMode( RouteOptions.TransportMode.PEDESTRIAN );
        routeResult.getRoute().getRoutePlan().getRouteOptions().setRouteType( RouteOptions.Type.SHORTEST );

        MapRoute newRoute = new MapRoute( routeResult.getRoute() );
        newRoute.setColor( Color.CYAN );
        map.addMapObject( newRoute );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You shout not modify `routeResult`, this object represents result of the route calculation. What you need is to set `routeOptions` with all its parameters before route is calculated, e.g. like [this](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/master/routing/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/routing/MapFragmentView.java#L162-L185).

Comment: I understand that, but I was wondering if there was anyway to modify the routeOptions for the routeResult given by rerouting. I would like to place the new route on the map and new directions without having to stop my current navigation and starting it on the new route.

Comment: I'm afraid it can not be done without recalculating route.